# Can you pass this as an argument to a renderless component in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Question is specifically relating to passing 'this' in order to set state within React renderless components

I am setting initial state from data retrieved from an XHR call. This works well in the main App like this:

```js
export default class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { someKey: [] };
  }
  
  XhrLoader() {
    const req = new XMLHttpRequest();
      ... 
    this.setState({someKey: [data]});
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.XhrLoader();
  }
}
```

In exporting the XhrLoader function you could pass 'this' to the module as:

```js
import XhrLoader from 'Xhrloader';
export default class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { someKey: [] };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.XhrLoader(this);
  }
}

  // imported module
  XhrLoader(app) {
    const req = new XMLHttpRequest();
      ... 
    app.setState({someKey: [data]});
  }
```

As an alternative you could also pass a bound component:

```js
export default class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { prodList: [] };
    this.SetState = this.SetState.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    XhrLoader(this.SetState);
  }

  SetState(newState) {
    this.setState(newState);
  }
}

// in XrhLoader
export default function XhrLoader(setAppState) {
 ...
 setAppState({someKey: newData)}
}
```

the component isn't rendering anything, usually would just pass data and methods via props:

```js
< XhrLoader setter={someBoundMethod} />
```

But that way performs unnecessary renders if rendering to return null

Is there a correct React style to achieve setting state from imported renderless components?

Comment: A better solution is to pass a callback: `XhrLoader(url, data => this.setState(...));` Which now makes the entire thing completely redundant, given that there's [`fetch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) (as for your question: I guess you can, why didn't you just try it yourself?)

Comment: why you don't use an HOC or render props?

Answer (score 2):

As [reactjs.org](http://reactjs.org) doc says:

> Conceptually, components are like JavaScript functions. They accept arbitrary inputs (called “props”) and **return React elements describing what should appear on the screen**.

then it is not a good pattern to use a component just for fetching data.

for that purpose if you create another JavaScript module (file) for your **XhrLoader** then import it in your component and use it in your **componentDidMount** with callback.

```
// xhrLoader module

export function xhrLoader(onSuccessCallback) {
   const req = new XMLHttpRequest();
   ... 
   if (onSuccessCallback) onSucceessCallback(result);
}

// App.jsx
import {xhrLoader} from "xhrLoader.js";

export default class App extends Component {
    constructor() {
       super();
       this.state = { prodList: [] };
    }
    componentDidMount() {
       const onSuccess = (result) => {
          this.setState({prodList: result});
       }
       xhrLoader(onSuccess);
    }
 }
```

also if you use libraries like [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) you can achieve your result with promise like this:

```
const axios = require('axios');

componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(url).then(resp => this.setState({prodList: resp.result}));
}
```